# PHP Mysql Query not working - Something to do with '+' symbol in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have code something like this:

```
$item = $_POST["item"];

$sql = "Select * FROM table WHERE item = '$item'";

$result = @mysql_query("$sql",$db);
```

If `$_POST["item"]` contains something like this `"Black + White Jumper"`

The query won't find an item, even if in the database there is an item called `"Black + White Jumper"`

Its something to do with the `+` symbol.

What can I do to fix this ?

Thanks

**The above isn't my actual code, so don't need replies about potential sql injection or stuff like that, just wondering how to get the '+' character to work in a query.

Comment: Use `urldecode($_POST["item"])`

Comment: You should escape your input with mysql_real_escape_string(). Mysql is obsolete, use mysqli instead.

Comment: you probably want to do some sort of validation on that post

Comment: works fine for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9658ef/1

Comment: None of these solutions work

Comment: my thoughts,  it would be better if each item had a unique id (maybe as a hidden field). Your form could supply the 'actual id' instead of  the 'selected' (Black + White Jumper) text.

Comment: Strange, you are not getting hits. Tried a number of variations, and got many more hits than expected. Doesn't seem to be tied to the `+`sign. (Identical results for underscore, and no character in that position.) Case doesn't seem to matter too much for MySQL either. Not even `INSTR` coming to the rescue: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/793319/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

Always wrap external input with `mysql_real_escape_string` to prevent errors and sql injection.

```
$sql = "Select * FROM table WHERE item = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item'])."'";
$result = mysql_query("$sql",$db);
```

Also suppressing errors with @ is not such a good idea. Use proper error handling. Secondly the mysql-extention is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, consider using mysqli or pdo.

Comment: agree, mysql_real_escape_string will do the job although I prefer OO style with prepare() and bind_param()

Comment: This solution is obsolete (hence the downvote). See prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

I will pass on the deprecated MySQL function and the lack of sanity check on the string, not object of the question here.

The query as it is presented should work if you are indeed looking for a specific string such as "Black + White Jumper" in the field `item`.

If you are looking for "Black Jumper" + "White Jumpers" as a result, the query should be:
$sql = "Select * FROM table WHERE item = 'Black Jumpers' OR item= 'White Jumper'";

Comment: This wouldn't work as an item cannot contain two separate strings at the same time. If you want to search for Black Jumper or White Jumper use `WHERE item = "Black Jumper" OR item = "White Jumper"`

Comment: Corrected - Thank you Random Hunter